# FOSSIL (version control system) does not add .htaccess files. Why?

Tags: windows, .htaccess, fossil

I have a website with many .htaccess files in it. But fossil does not save them in repo when I use addremove. Instead, I have to add each htaccess file by hand (using the add command). What is happening?

Fossil 1.22 (2012-03-17 17:53:25), Win32.

Answer (score 5):

From fossil help for the 'addremove' command:

> Files and directories whose names begin with "." are ignored unless the --dotfiles option is used.